# Search and Append to a pattern without affecting anything else in Vim

Tags: vim, replace, vi

I have a number of lines like this:

`pointer->[some Random Number Of Alphabets](),`

I want to search for this pattern and append `.value()` to it exactly after the `()` so it becomes `pointer->[some Random Number Of Alphabets]().value(),` but what happens is it overwrites the `","` and the space after it which I'm intending to leave unaffected. the command I'm using is this:

`%s/\(\<pointer->.*()\), \>/\1.value()/`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `\ze` in these cases

```
:%s/\<pointer->.*()\ze, /&.value()/
```

- `\ze` marks the end of the match
- `&` is equivalent to `\0`
- remove the `\>` as I feel like this is an accident. See `:h /\>`
- May want to use an non-greedy qualifier like `\{-}` instead of `*`, better yet maybe `[^(]*`
- May want to use `\zs` to the mark start of the match and eliminate the need for `&`. See @Pak's comment below

For more help see:

```
:h /\ze
:h s/\&
:h /\>
:h /\{-
```

Comment: Taking the `\ze` method a bit further, you can also use `\zs` to mark the start of the match.  This eliminates the need to include the original part of the match in the replacement part.  This would make it: `:%s/\<pointer->.*()\zs\ze, /.value()/`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
:%s/\v(pointer.*\(\))/\1.value()/
```